# UITableView crash Unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, crash

My program crashes with the below report.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb4e1c099b0'
```

Here is my implementation of the tableview method.

Crash log [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/283415d293042edc7c00d476df98d774).

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        if (section == 0) {
            return 6;
        } 
        return 5;
    }
```

Can any one has any idea why this is happening?

Comment: else if if ???? and section is only one than why you need to check section is 0 or not??

Comment: your `tableview` always return 1 for `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: Please share the complete crash log.

Comment: I have modified the code above to show i got only one section and still it crashes. Here is a complete crash log.   https://gist.github.com/anonymous/283415d293042edc7c00d476df98d774

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says you are sending the method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` to a UIView object, which does not understand that method.  Either your tableview's data source is incorrect, or you meant to send a different method to the UIView.

If you cannot find the line of code with your bug, you might share more code.  Otherwise, the code you have posted is just boilerplate and is unhelpful.  But that is what your error message means.

Comment: You were right. In the interface builder. The tableview datasource and delegate was linked to the UIView rather than Files owner. Now the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You have only one section and syntax error near else if if(section == 0)
It would treat like 'if' inside 'else if'

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        if (section == 0) {
            return 6;
        } 
        else if (section == 1) {
            return 3;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
 }

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     if section == 0 {
        return firstSectionArray.count
     }else if section == 1{
        return secondSectionArray.count
     }
     return 0;
 }
```